# Need to understand the below sql code

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Case 

WHEN p_con.pipeline_tx_status in (('CNF'),'OI','ICF','C')
   (p_con.pipeline_tx_status in ('CNF') OR  (p_con.pipeline_tx_status in('OI','ICF','C') AND NVL(MWB_HEADER.ACCOUNTING_STATUS,'O') NOT IN ('O'))) 

THEN "CNF"
```

Comment: This code will not compile. I'm afraid we can explain the logic of code which is not properly written.

Answer (score 0):

```
if 
    pipeline_tx_status's value eqauls ('CNF' or 'OI' or 'ICF' or 'C')
    (and? / or?) pipeline_tx_status's value eqauls 'CNF'
    and pipeline_tx_status's value eqauls ('OI' or 'ICF' or 'C') 
    and MWB_HEADER.ACCOUNTING_STATUS not null
then the value return "CNF"

ps.p_con,MWB_HEADER are your table varible
```

---

you have to know these knowloges below

[SQL IN Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

[Oracle / PLSQL: NVL Function](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php)